# Grails and Accumulo, getting a bug in Accumulo's jar

Tags: grails, groovy

I am trying to connect Grails to Accumulo but I am getting a bug in what appears to be Accumulo-core.jar.

I cam getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on org.apache.accumulo.core.security.thrift.AuthInfo

After digging I found that:

1) Grails can't find that if I import it myself. It throws an import error.

and

2) This line of code at the bottom of ZooKeeperInstance.class is what is messing up the whole project:

```
  public org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Connector getConnector(org.apache.accumulo.core.security.thrift.AuthInfo auth)
```

That path is in the jar, I am staring at it. I actually can't use *anything* in the security.thrift path. But I can use the rest of security. Very odd.

Does anyone have any clue what is going on?

Comment: Accumulo-core.jar is in your lib folder? Try `grails compile --refresh-dependencies`

Comment: I just used maven instead and it worked fine. I think I was using a corrupted jar.

Comment: Cool, post it as answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To anyone finding this issue, use Maven instead of putting it in the lib directory. I am not really sure why this was the answer, but give it a try.